# Positioning of Bar plot in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, bar-chart

I try to have two bar plots side by side in using tikzpicture in subfigure. In my document, it looks like this:

[image]

This does not look good. 
Problems are:

1. It covers partly the text.
2. The 2 bar plots too close to each other.

How to proceed further?

I used the following:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
%\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=75mm,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        ylabel=YLABEL,
        xlabel= {XLABEL},
        legend style={
          at={(0,1)},
          anchor=north west,
        },
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=6pt
      ]
      \addplot[gray!20!gray,fill=gray!80!gray]
        coordinates {(01,0.150) (02,0.166)
          (03,0.174) (04,0.186) (05,0.187) (06,0.152) (07,0.218) (08,0.187) (09,0.156)};
      \addplot[black!20!black,fill=black!80!black]
        coordinates {(01,0.153) (02,0.162) 
          (03,0.178) (04,0.177) (05,0.222) (06,0.233) (07,0.323) (08,0.301) (09,0.233)};
      \legend{Measured, Model}
    \end{axis}
    \caption[BLABLA]
{{\small BLABLA123}}    
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
 \begin{axis}[
      height=75mm,% 
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        ylabel=YLABEL,
        xlabel= {XLABEL},
        legend style={
          at={(0,1)},
          anchor=north west,
        },
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=6pt
      ]
      \addplot[gray!20!gray,fill=gray!80!gray]
        coordinates {(01,0.150) (02,0.166)
          (03,0.174) (04,0.186) (05,0.187) (06,0.152) (07,0.218) (08,0.187) (09,0.156)};
      \addplot[black!20!black,fill=black!80!black]
        coordinates {(01,0.153) (02,0.162) 
          (03,0.178) (04,0.177) (05,0.222) (06,0.233) (07,0.323) (08,0.301) (09,0.233)};
      \legend{Measured, Model}
    \end{axis}
        \caption[BLABLA456]
{{\small BLABLA567}}    
    \end{subfigure}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: In future pleas provide complete MWE not only code snipped. The information about preamble in your document (only a part which is essential to generate your problem) are very valuable in preparing an answer and help us to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had not:

- nested `subfigure` environments in `tikzpicture` environments!
- have `caption` inside `tikzpicture`
- define font size of caption in caption. It and other options should be defined with `captionsetup` in preamble.

After reorganizing of your MWE I obtain:

[image]

In MWE I also add `showframe` package that oage layout is wisibel In document production it had to be removed. The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.13}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=25mm,
            showframe
            ]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=75mm,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        ylabel=YLABEL,
        xlabel= {XLABEL},
        legend style={
          at={(0,1)},
          anchor=north west,
        },
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=6pt
      ]
      \addplot[gray!20!gray,fill=gray!80!gray]
        coordinates {(01,0.150) (02,0.166)
          (03,0.174) (04,0.186) (05,0.187) (06,0.152) (07,0.218) (08,0.187) (09,0.156)};
      \addplot[black!20!black,fill=black!80!black]
        coordinates {(01,0.153) (02,0.162)
          (03,0.178) (04,0.177) (05,0.222) (06,0.233) (07,0.323) (08,0.301) (09,0.233)};
      \legend{Measured, Model}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[BLABLA]{BLABLA123}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      height=75mm,%
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        ylabel=YLABEL,
        xlabel= {XLABEL},
        legend style={
          at={(0,1)},
          anchor=north west,
        },
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=6pt
      ]
      \addplot[gray!20!gray,fill=gray!80!gray]
        coordinates {(01,0.150) (02,0.166)
          (03,0.174) (04,0.186) (05,0.187) (06,0.152) (07,0.218) (08,0.187) (09,0.156)};
      \addplot[black!20!black,fill=black!80!black]
        coordinates {(01,0.153) (02,0.162)
          (03,0.178) (04,0.177) (05,0.222) (06,0.233) (07,0.323) (08,0.301) (09,0.233)};
      \legend{Measured, Model}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[BLABLA456]{BLABLA567}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution! I want to have 2 more things to be changed. First, the values about the bars are too close to each other. For example, bar 2  the 0.17 is almost on top of 0.16. How do I increase the space? Secondly, the x-axis is not entirely visible. I want all the numbers 1 to 9, but I only see 2, 4, 6, 8. How to proceed from here?

Comment: Your wishes seems to be new question ... :-). the second on is easy to solve with adding `xtick={1,2,...,9}`  however for nodes above bars simply is not enough place: bars are to narrow. Solution seems to be: (i) omit this numbers (ii) instead `ybar` use `xbar (rotate diagram).