# tikzpicture plots side by side

Tags: floats, subcaption

Yes I have looked at [other solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319507/positioning-of-bar-plot-in-latex), for some reason they don't work. They produce a set of images that are not centered, this can be seen in the following image.
[image: not centered]

Currently, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref} % add hyperlinks to refs
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % centering floats
\usepackage{float} % H

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel={$n$},
        ylabel={$\boldsymbol{x[n]}$},
         xtick={-2, -1, ..., 2},
         width  = 0.4 * 8.5in,
        ]
        \addplot [ycomb, black, thick, mark=*] coordinates {
          (-1, -1)
          (0, 1)
          (1, -1)
          (2, 2)
        };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{x[n] Base signal;}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfil
  % add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
  % (or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel={$n$},
        ylabel={$\boldsymbol{x[n]}$},
         xtick={-2, -1, ..., 2},
         width  = 0.4 * 8.5in,
        ]
        \addplot [ycomb, black, thick, mark=*] coordinates {
          (0, -1)
          (1, 1)
          (2, -1)
          (3, 2)
        };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{x[n-1] shifted }
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I think the problem is related to the log output `Overfull \hbox (63.08745pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 34--35` but I'm not sure how to address this, any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The overlap comes, I think, from the fact that you squeeze the plots too much by saying `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}`. If you use `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}` instead, the overlap gets reduced, but is still nonzero. So you may either make smaller plots or put them under each other.

Comment: I assume you use letter format, so your paper width is 8.5in. `\textwidth` refers to the width of the text, which is smaller than the paper width. In your example, the subfigure has `.4\textwidth` while the tikzpicture has `.4*8.5in` which is obviously larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you determine too much width of the diagram. try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth,% <--- accomodate diagram width to subfigure width
             axis lines=center,
             axis on top,
             xmin=-1.2, xmax=2.5,
             ymin=-1.2, ymax=2.5,
             x tick label style={font=\footnotesize, fill=white, yshift=-2pt},
             xlabel={$n$},
             x label style={anchor=west},
             ylabel={$\boldsymbol{x[n]}$},
             y label style={anchor=west},
             every axis plot post/.append style={ultra thick, black},
             },
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
        \addplot +[ycomb] coordinates { (-1, -1) (0, 1) (1, -1) (2, 2) };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$x[n]$ Base signal}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfil
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
        \addplot +[ycomb] coordinates { (0, -1) (1, 1) (2, -1) (3, 2) };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$x[n-1]$ shifted }
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

in above code i took liberty and made the following changes in your diagrams' code:

- definitions of axis properties i move to common `\pgfplotsset` for this image (by this the code for figure is shorter)
- to diagrams options i add `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax`, by which i slightly increase axis (to my taste this looks better, if you not like this, just remove those definitions),
- change `xtick` and `ytick` label size, to `xtick label` also add `fill=white` that are now better visible
- move axis on the top
- define plotted lines style in `pgfplotset`
- option to `\addplot` add with `+` (as `\addplot +[ycomb] ...`)

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I couldnt compile with your `ycomb*` addition, but simply changing to `ycomb` worked. Is is possible to move the numbers in the graph so they dont cutout the data lines ?

Comment: @sp00kyb00g13, where you find in my code `ycomb*`? numbers over data lines you can move above `x axis` as `extra xticks` and defining style for them. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406585/

Comment: `\addplot +[ycomb*] coordinates { (0, -1) (1, 1) (2, -1) (3, 2) };` and thanks I'll look at that post.

Comment: @sp00kyb00g13, at second diagram. this is typo. corrected now.